# Extbase Ajaxdispatcher gives error "The default controller can not be determined"

Tags: ajax, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I am using typo3 6.2.12. I built an extension and I would like to render the Ajax data with Ajax dispatcher and i get following exception
"The default controller can not be determined"

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this for eID based ajax

https://mihirbhatt4687.wordpress.com/2014/06/24/ajax-in-extbase/

OR

this for typeNum based ajax

http://lbrmedia.net/codebase/Eintrag/extbase-60-ajax-bootstrap/